# Using an array to assing a integer value to an enter(break etc.)

Tags: php, arrays, enter

I'm trying to let an array assign an integer(decimal) value to an 'enter' key retrieved from a string. But it doesn't work *yet*. Tried *'\r' => 149*, *'\n\r' => 149*, *'\n' => 149* and *'\r\n' => 149*.

This is the array currently:

```
$numbers = array( // Epic long array //
'a' => 0, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 3, 'e' => 4,
'f' => 5, 'g' => 6, 'h' => 7, 'i' => 8, 'j' => 9,
'k' => 10, 'l' => 11, 'm' => 12, 'n' => 13, 'o' => 14,
'p' => 15, 'q' => 16, 'r' => 17, 's' => 18, 't' => 19,
'u' => 20, 'v' => 21, 'w' => 22, 'x' => 23, 'y' => 24,
'z' => 25, 'A' => 26, 'B' => 27, 'C' => 28, 'D' => 29,
'E' => 30, 'F' => 31, 'G' => 32, 'H' => 33, 'I' => 34,
'J' => 35, 'K' => 36, 'L' => 37, 'M' => 38, 'N' => 39,
'O' => 40, 'P' => 41, 'Q' => 42, 'R' => 43, 'S' => 44,
'T' => 45, 'U' => 46, 'V' => 47, 'W' => 48, 'X' => 49,
'Y' => 50, 'Z' => 51, 0 => 52, 1 => 53, 2 => 54,
3 => 55, 4 => 56, 5 => 57, 6 => 58, 7 => 59,
8 => 60, 9 => 61, ' ' => 62, '.' => 63, ',' => 64,
';' => 65, ':' => 66, '\'' => 67, '"' => 68, '[' => 69,
']' => 70, '{' => 71, '}' => 72, '(' => 73, ')' => 74,
'+' => 75, '-' => 76, '@' => 77, '#' => 78, '$' => 79,
'%' => 80, '^' => 81, '&' => 82, '*' => 83, '!' => 84,
'?' => 85, '<' => 86, '>' => 87, '/' => 88, '\\' => 89,
'|' => 90, '=' => 91, '`' => 92, '~' => 93, '€' => 94,
'«' => 95, '»' => 96, '¥' => 97, '£' => 98, 'é' => 99,
'è' => 100, 'ê' => 101, 'ë' => 102, 'ó' => 103, 'ò' => 104,
'ö' => 105, 'ô' => 106, 'õ' => 107, 'á' => 108, 'à' => 109,
'â' => 110, 'ä' => 111, 'ã' => 112, 'í' => 113, 'ì' => 114,
'ï' => 115, 'î' => 116, 'ú' => 117, 'ù' => 118, 'û' => 119,
'ü' => 120, 'ç' => 121, '©' => 122, '™' => 123, 'ø' => 124,
'É' => 125, 'È' => 126, 'Ë' => 127, 'Ó' => 128, 'Ò' => 129,
'Ö' => 130, 'Ô' => 131, 'Õ' => 132, 'Á' => 133, 'À' => 134,
'Â' => 135, 'Ä' => 136, 'Ã' => 137, 'Í' => 138, 'Ì' => 139,
'Ï' => 140, 'Î' => 141, 'Ú' => 142, 'Ù' => 143, 'Û' => 144,
'Ü' => 145, 'Ç' => 146, 'Ø' => 147, '÷' => 148, '\r' => 149 
);
```

Comment: haven't you heard about [`chr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) and [`odr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odr.php)

Comment: Good point. What are you trying got do exactly? Can you show us more code because it might help us suggest a better solution :)

Comment: This is just a conversion table I made to be able to edit the characters easily instead of the ASCII-table. This way it is easier to debug, and that's important since it's a project creating a encryption and decryption system with our own algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the escape characters in double quotes, i.e:

```
"\n"
```

Comment: Thanks! That one nailed it!
Although I did have to add two keys("\n" and "\r") for it to work fully.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

"*If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters:*"